# Python: why does importing a package sometimes grant access to modules underneath it but sometimes not?

Tags: python, python-import

Python import mechanism is always a myth for me. Sometimes importing a package can grant access to the modules underneath it. For instance,

```
import urllib
urllib.parse.unquote
```

gives

```
<function urllib.parse.unquote>
```

which shows functions are accessible even with only the package (i.e. urllib in this case) imported but not down to the module file. This is done within Jupyter notebook.

But when I do the same thing in terminal

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.parse.unquote
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'parse'
```

Both Python versions are 3.6.1.

What makes the difference and what is the good practice?

## EDIT to combine the answers by @user2357112 and @Tomoki.

#### Directly from @user2357112

> For an access to urllib.parse to work, the following two conditions must be true:
>
> The `urllib` module object must be bound to the `urllib` name, whether in the local, global, or some enclosing scope.
>   The `urllib.parse` submodule must have been initialized and bound to the parse attribute of the `urllib` module object.
>   An import `urllib` in the current local or global scope (or any enclosing scope) satisfies the first condition.
>
> An `import urllib.parse` executed anywhere in the program satisfies the second condition, since it loads the submodule and binds it to the `parse` attribute on the `urllib` module object, and there's only one `urllib` module object for the whole program.
>
> In the environments where `urllib.parse` was accessible after a simple import `urllib`, some other code must have loaded `urllib.parse`, causing you to see it.

#### The evidence is provided by @Tomoki

```
Test: "import IPython"
 └─IPython:┐
      ┌────┘
      ├──"from core.application import Application"
      │   └──IPython.core.application: "from IPython.core import release, crashhandler"
      │      └──IPython.core.crashhandler: "from IPython.core import ultratb"
      │         └──IPython.core.ultratb: "import pydoc"
      │            └──pydoc: "import urllib.parse"
      └──"from terminal.embed import embed"
          └──IPython.terminal.embed:┐
                        ┌───────────┘
                        ├──"from IPython.core import magic_arguments"
                        │   └──IPython.core.magic_arguments: "from IPython.utils.text import dedent"
                        │      └──IPython.utils.text: "from pathlib import Path"
                        │         └──pathlib: "from urllib.parse import quote_from_bytes"
                        ├──"from IPython.core.magic import Magics, magics_class, line_magic"
                        │   └──IPython.core.magic: "from IPython.core import oinspect"
                        │      └──IPython.core.oinspect: "from IPython.core import page"
                        │         └──IPython.core.page: "from IPython.core.display import display"
                        │            └──IPython.core.display: "import mimetypes"
                        │               └──mimetypes: "import urllib.parse"
                        └──"from IPython.terminal.interactiveshell import TerminalInteractiveShell"
                            └──pygments.plugin: "import pkg_resources"
                               └──pkg_resources: "import email.parser"
                                  └──email.parser: "from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser"
                                     └──email.feedparser: "from email._policybase import compat32"
                                        └──email._policybase: "from email.utils import _has_surrogates"
                                           └──email.utils: "import urllib.parse"
```

The last line indeed touches `urllib.parse`.

#### Another Evidence

`import scipy` does not provide access to `scipy.stats.norm` in either a terminal or Jupyter notebook because none of the environment touches `scipy.stats` at all.

## What is the good practice?

We can conclude from above that it is not only a good practice, but in fact a requirement to ##import the whole module levels##.

#### "Always import down to file (module) level to guarantee the access"

Thanks all for the answers!

Comment: Both of your code samples fail for me in Python 3.5.  Is your first code snippet taken from a file in which other modules are imported before `urllib`?

Comment: The 1st snippet is working in Jupyter notebook with a fresh start. The server version is 5.0.0

Comment: It has to do with how the creator wrote the  __init__.py its a good exercise to write your first setup.py and __init__.py to see how this plays out.

Comment: @SimonHobbs Good point. But the file __init__.py under the official package urllib is an empty file. And given that the two scenarios above are for the *same* package, if setup.py makes the difference, the two snippets above should work the same. But the fact that it is not the case really puzzles me.

Comment: This is weird... It works in IDLE and Spyder, in Ipython and when I run it from a file. However, it does not work in terminal at all (in the shell, and running a file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an access to `urllib.parse` to work, the following two conditions must be true:

1. The `urllib` module object must be bound to the `urllib` name, whether in the local, global, or some enclosing scope.
2. The `urllib.parse` submodule must have been initialized and bound to the `parse` attribute of the `urllib` module object.

An `import urllib` in the current local or global scope (or any enclosing scope) satisfies the first condition.

An `import urllib.parse` executed *anywhere in the program* satisfies the second condition, since it loads the submodule and binds it to the `parse` attribute on the `urllib` module object, and there's only one `urllib` module object for the whole program.

In the environments where `urllib.parse` was accessible after a simple `import urllib`, some other code must have loaded `urllib.parse`, causing you to see it.

Answer (score 2):

Like user2357112 said it's getting imported; I believe these are the specific modules and statements.

```
Test: "import IPython"
 └─IPython:┐
      ┌────┘
      ├──"from core.application import Application"
      │   └──IPython.core.application: "from IPython.core import release, crashhandler"
      │      └──IPython.core.crashhandler: "from IPython.core import ultratb"
      │         └──IPython.core.ultratb: "import pydoc"
      │            └──pydoc: "import urllib.parse"
      └──"from terminal.embed import embed"
          └──IPython.terminal.embed:┐
                        ┌───────────┘
                        ├──"from IPython.core import magic_arguments"
                        │   └──IPython.core.magic_arguments: "from IPython.utils.text import dedent"
                        │      └──IPython.utils.text: "from pathlib import Path"
                        │         └──pathlib: "from urllib.parse import quote_from_bytes"
                        ├──"from IPython.core.magic import Magics, magics_class, line_magic"
                        │   └──IPython.core.magic: "from IPython.core import oinspect"
                        │      └──IPython.core.oinspect: "from IPython.core import page"
                        │         └──IPython.core.page: "from IPython.core.display import display"
                        │            └──IPython.core.display: "import mimetypes"
                        │               └──mimetypes: "import urllib.parse"
                        └──"from IPython.terminal.interactiveshell import TerminalInteractiveShell"
                            └──pygments.plugin: "import pkg_resources"
                               └──pkg_resources: "import email.parser"
                                  └──email.parser: "from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser"
                                     └──email.feedparser: "from email._policybase import compat32"
                                        └──email._policybase: "from email.utils import _has_surrogates"
                                           └──email.utils: "import urllib.parse"
```

Comment: WOW! I think we already put together the final answer. And how did you generate this tree chart? It is beautiful!

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 does not load the helper modules for urllib automatically. ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html )

"Note The urllib module has been split into parts and renamed in Python 3 to urllib.request, urllib.parse, and urllib.error. The 2to3 tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to Python 3."

"Note urllib also exposes certain utility functions like splittype, splithost and others parsing URL into various components. But it is recommended to use urlparse for parsing URLs rather than using these functions directly. Python 3 does not expose these helper functions from urllib.parse module."

---

If you attempt to query the urllib namespace dir(urllib) after import, there are no submodules.  After you type urllib.parse.unquote and get the error,  the urllib helper modules are loaded. (I'm serious, that sounds crazy and wrong, all things not Python, "he's a n00b", just try it.) You can see them in the namespace through dir(urllib) and can query use them as if they were all loaded initially.  You will then get the function object return.

`Python 3.5.2 (default, Aug 18 2017, 17:48:00)`
`[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux`
`Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`

`>>> import urllib`

`>>> urllib.parse.unquote`

`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>`
`AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'parse'`

`>>> urllib.parse.unquote`

`<function unquote at 0x7f559e4768c8>`

---

In the six module, there are builtins.module(builtins.object)

```
    Module_six_moves_urllib
_LazyDescr(builtins.object)
    MovedAttribute
    MovedModule
_LazyModule(builtins.module)
    Module_six_moves_urllib_error
    Module_six_moves_urllib_parse
    Module_six_moves_urllib_request
    Module_six_moves_urllib_response
    Module_six_moves_urllib_robotparser
```

There is additional documentation (of course) such as

class Module_six_moves_urllib(builtins.module)
"     |  Create a six.moves.urllib namespace that resembles the Python 3 namespace"

I suspect that terminal does not invoke the builtin to load the helper modules automatically where as Jupyter does though I honestly don't know.

Edit to add:  Importing urllib, importing six and calling on it [even help("six")] will load the parse, request, response, robotparser modules to the urllib namespace.  Additionally, importing urllib and calling help on it will load parse but not the other modules into the namespace.  Jupyter may be loading help proactively causing it to load the parse module only.  I don't have IPython/conda/Jupyter installed so can't help to test.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think what it says "Python 3 does not expose these helper functions from urllib.parse module" means that we cannot call `urllib.urlparser` directly. We still need to go down one level ourselves `urlliab.parse.urlparser`.  I tried `help("six")` and it does make `urlliab.parse.unquote` possible after `import urllib` only. The reason is probably what @user2357112 stated: six touches `urlliab.parse` somewhere so making it available.

Comment: "After you type urllib.parse.unquote and get the error, the urllib helper modules are loaded" - can't reproduce, on 3.6.0 or 3.4.6. Something in your setup probably loads `urllib.parse` as a side effect of the exception reporting machinery.