# How does tensorflow import work?

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I do `import tensorflow as tf`, I can access different packages inside `tf`: `tf.nn`, `tf.train`, etc

BUT accessing `tensorflow.examples` fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-c704d4902e0c>", line 1, in <module>
    tf.examples
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'examples'
```

I have to import it differently, like `from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data`, and only after that `tf.examples` does resolve. Why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46478864/python-why-does-importing-a-package-sometimes-grant-access-to-modules-underneat